# How to send Data into php file using angular and send email using php with mobile 10 digit validation

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a form there is 4 input Name, Mobile, Email and Message I want to submit form data into php file using angular and also validation on every field with mobile 10 digit. And in php also again validate all form filled also mobile and send it into email

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Try to look at a Contact form Demo online, you will get what you want

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of way to share data between two lang, but API is most efficient. 
Following [link](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2015/12/angularjs-crud-example-php.html) might help